# Python automatic debugging configuration missing in VSCodium even though Python Extension installed?

Tags: python, vscodium

I'm using vscodium (version 1.85.1), I installed the official python extension (ms-python).

I'm looking to debug a python file using breakpoints that can I can do some simple type inspection.

When I click "run and debug", and then I click "show all automatic debug configurations", I expect to see python as a debug configuration, however it does not appear.

Would anyone know why?

I've tried setting the interpreter for my virtual environment using the command palette and it is set to the correct one.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.... I'll post here if I figure out how to fix it. If you figured out please update with a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cross posted this question on github for VSCodium and someone presented a workaround there.

https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1801

Use the following for launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": true,
    }
]
```

}

The user also made the following comment.

`However, as you can see in the screenshot, I get a warning saying that the python configuration will be deprecated soon, and to replace it with debugpy. Unfortunately, when I try replacing it with debugpy, I get taken to the extensions marketplace with no search results, so I assume debugpy is not available on VS Codium.`